# Presence of UIToolbar affecting layout of view controller's view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitoolbar, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController subclass that displays 1 view controller at a time. The displayed view controller has a scrollview. This allows the user to scroll left/right to go to a new page, or up down to view content larger than the screen's height. The UIPageViewController subclass is embedded within a UINavigationController, and the navBar's toolbar is visible.

This UIPageViewController subclass can be accessed from two different parts of my app.

In my first viewController, the toolbar is **hidden**. Tapping on an element in this view controller loads the UIPageViewController, and everything looks fine.

In my second viewController, the toolbar is **visible**. Tapping on an element in this view controller loads the UIPageViewController, but my content (the pageViewController's viewController) is pushed down a bit from the navigation bar. As soon as I interact with the scrollView though, the view automatically adjusts to correctly sit right below the nav bar.

I am running this on iOS7, but I'm not sure if that has any relation.

Why is my view controller loading differently when coming from two different parts of the app, one with the toolbar showing, one with it hidden?

Comment: It appears to be a bug in how the "UIPageViewController" in Storyboard lays out the views.  As far as I could tell, the frame positions of the pageController.view and the individual view controllers were both at (0,0), and the size width/height matched the device frame.

Comment: interesting. sounds like we were having similar problems, but I'm not using Storyboards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app works well on iOS6, but not on iOS7, try to set **NO** to UIPageViewController(UIPVC)'s **automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets** property.

UIPVC seems to have a scrollview inside. On iOS7, UIViewController's automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets property is set to YES in default. I think it doesn't work well if it is embedded in UINavigationController.

In my case, I created custom UIPVC and place the following code in [viewDidLoad] method.

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Comment: whoa! i could have sworn I tried that and it didn't work for me, but now it worked great! maybe I tried it during the early ios7 betas and now it's fixed in the GM. anyways, a much cleaner solution than what I resorted to.

Comment: I am finding that this "automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets" flag is causing nothing but trouble.  Usually I would assume that I am using it incorrectly but the behavior is inconsistent no matter how I use it so I just always set it to "NO" now.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to properly align an embedded UIPageViewController in a NavController, which itself is inside a TabBarcontroller.  I did so by programmatically creating the pageViewController inside a dummy "rootviewcontroller", following the example given in the default Xcode "New Project" called "Page-based Application".

In my case, the following storyboard layout produce the error: TabBarController -> NavController -> UIPageViewController (scroll-horizontal) -> ContentViewController

I changed my storyboard layout to: TabBarController -> NavController -> CustomRootViewController

The CustomRootViewController instantiates a UIPageViewController and saves it as a member property.  CustomRootViewController becomes the DataSource and Delegate for its PageViewController.  Follow the default Xcode "New Project" called "Page-based Application" for an example of how to setup the RootViewController.

Unfortunately, this whole issue appears to be caused by a bug in Storyboard when you are using the drag-and-drop "UIPageViewController", with scroll-horizontal transition-type, embedded in a navController (and/or tabbarcontroller).  FYI - In the pageViewController's viewWillAppear, I tried resetting the frame of the pageViewController and the contentViewControllers each to (0,0) with size matching the device, and yet the view of the pageViewController's initial viewController would always be shifted-down by what appeared to be the height of the tabbarcontroller in which it was embedded.  Here are a few observations for those who wish to pursue this issue further:

1. In viewDidLoad, you can set the Frame of the pageViewController's initial view to offset the layout-error.  But then you might have to deal with different layout-corrections for different devices in different orientations, and that could be a headache down the road.
2. In Storyboard, setting the pageViewController's transition style to "page curl" resolves the layout issue.  So therefore I am certain that the layout issue resides in page-scroll, which is set upon instantiation.  Instantiation by Storyboard will produce the layout error, but instantiation programmatically in my CustomRootViewController is error-free.

Comment: Nice suggestion. What's odd is that I was having this issue early on in development, and I had your suggested VC hierarchy (without a tab bar controller). My fix was to remove the PageVC from the rootVC and just subclass PageVC directly. Now, several weeks later I'm having the same problem, so I wonder if something changed between then (ios7 betas) and now (ios7 gm). i'll definitely give it a shot.

Comment: It would certainly appear to be a bug.  The Apple Doc's say that PageViewController is NOT to be embedded in other controls, so we are in unsupported territory as far as our use of the PVC.  IMPORTANT - My suggestion above is NO GOOD FOR IOS6, the app will crash due to some autorelease issue with the constraints of the scrollview.  I have abandoned using PVC's embedded in TBC and NC, and have gone back to simply embedding a scrollView into a viewController.  10x easier.  IMHO, PVC is only useful if you do not embed it.

Comment: i've read the class documentation of UIPVC and don't see any warning relating to embedding it in other controllers. Can you pass along a link? There are several sections of my app that require paging (full screen and tableviewcell) and I find using a PVC so much easier because it handles dequeueing and caching and what not. I'd like to try to avoid that by building my own on top of UIScrollView

Comment: Sorry, I believe I misspoke on PVC having to be the initial view controller.  I was thinking of this section of the apple docs "Creating a Page View Controller Interface Using a Storyboard" step 4: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/PageViewControllers.html  In my personal experience and from the apple examples I've seen, it seems to me that the PVC is meant to be used as the initial view controller, and as of yet I have not been able to resolve the layout/constraints errors that appear when embedding in NC's and TBC's.